# What is this ios presentation style called?

Tags: ios5, uialertview, modalviewcontroller

When you use the mail app on iPhone and you click on the little flag icon and it presents a dialog from the bottom of the screen that says: Flag, Mark as Read, and Cancel. What is that presentation style called?

Answer (score 0):

`UIActionSheet` ([Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html))